# Facebook Sharing postID returning null Android

Tags: android, facebook

There are two cases when the user is sharing to Facebook.

When user **doesn't have** Facebook app installed on his device, I can share the content using `ShareLinkContent`, `ShareDialog` and `CallbackManager`. After sharing is done, `onSuccess(Sharer.Result result)` is called and I can get `postId` by calling `result.getPostId();` with no problem. The `postId` is something like 1492503807719975_1492539597716396.

However, when user **has** the Facebook native app installed on his device, I still share the content the same way and it is done successfully, but in this case, `postId` I get from `result.getPostId();` is `null`.

Can anyone tell what might be the reason?

Thanks.

Here is the code of my activity:

```
private CallbackManager mFacebookCallbackManager;
private ShareDialog     mFacebookShareDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mFacebookShareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    mFacebookShareDialog.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, this);
}

private void shareOnFacebook()
{
    ShareLinkContent.Builder builder = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle(mTitle)
            .setContentDescription(mContent)
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(mURL));

    if (!mImageURL.isEmpty())
    {
        builder.setImageUrl(Uri.parse(mImageURL));
    }

    mFacebookShareDialog.show(builder.build());
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result)
{
    String postID = result.getPostId();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: The Share dialog is only supposed to return a post id if the user has logged in to your app and granted it `publish_actions` permission.

Comment: But I get post id  when there is no Facebook app installed. Shouldn't I be able to get post id when user has the app as well?

Comment: Actually the Share Dialog does not require "publish_actions" permission  "Publishing via dialogs or social plugins does not require this permission. Do not request review of this permission if you're only using Share dialog, Feed Dialog, Message Dialog etc,"  Source:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5

Comment: As per @CBroe, try requesting the `publish_actions` and see if you get the post id back. In general you shouldn't be getting a post id if you didn't request the `publish_actions` permission as per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) (*see Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story.*).

Comment: @ifaour thank you! Why was [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) (the docs link you just gave) so hard to find out for me?